# Damping in the gravitational waves

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, gravitational-waves

Is the gravitational waves detected by LIGO in a damped state? If its is not in a damped state then what possibly would be the damping factor that can damp the gravitational waves?

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain what you mean by damped gravitational waves?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by damped is that they decrease is some way, that happens towards the end of the merger. After starting the final merger they have some characteristic oscillations which then die down very very quickly and no more grav waves.

The mechanism is that what they radiate is due to asymmetries, principally from quadrupole moments but also to higher moments. In the final stage the characteristics oscillations get rid of any final asymmetries and when it's all axially or spherically symmetric it achieves a stationary state (Schwarzschild for spherical, Kerr for rotating axially symmetric), and conservation of energy and momentum and angular momentum don't allow any more gravitational radiation.

The stage when black holes are spiraling towards each other is called the i spiral stage. Towards the end of it the black holes go at about half c/2 around each other and produce the strongest waves as they start merging. The frequency increases as in a chirp wave, and the energy released also. Then it dires down in what is called the ringdown phase as they get rid of remaining asymmetries till they settle down.

See more at Wikipedia at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves

See also the LIGO collaboration homepage. They have links and references to papers on grav. Waves and how they calculated the gravitational waves they should be seeing for different parameters of the black holes. They have descriptions of both the i spiral and ringdown phases. http://www.ligo.org

The damping is simply as they radiate energy and other moments away they are getting rid of asymmetries, and eventually they have only what black holes are allowed to have: mass (energy), angular momentum if rotating, and charge if any unbalanced charge remains. Everything else gets radiated.

To see more basic calculations of black holes see the general relativity book by Thorne, Misner and Wheeler. You will see there that any dyNamic configuration of mass energy will radiate quadrupole moments and above, and nothing lower. And also that black holes which are not symmetric at first will radiate it all away till axially or spherically symmetric. It is the conserved entities under symmetries which damp down further gravitational radiation.